# Segmentation fault while upgrading on 20.04

Tags: apt, upgrade, 20.10, segmentation-fault, apport

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  bsdmainutils calendar fonts-mathjax g++-9 gir1.2-mutter-6
  ippusbxd libcdio18 libcfitsio8 libcollada-dom2.4-dp0
  libdc1394-22 libdns-export1109 libdvdread7 libebml4v5
  libedataserver-1.2-24 libffi7 libffi7:i386 libgeos-3.8.0
  libhogweed5 libhogweed5:i386 libicu66 libicu66:i386
  libilmbase24 libjs-mathjax libjson-c4 libmatroska6v5
  libmozjs-68-0 libmpdec2 libmutter-6-0 libnettle7
  libnettle7:i386 libopenexr24 libplacebo7 libpoppler97
  libproj15 libprotobuf-lite17 libprotobuf17 libqhull7 libqpdf26
  libre2-5 libreoffice-style-tango libsane libsrt1 libtepl-4-0
  libx264-155 libx264-155:i386 libx265-179 libx265-179:i386
  linux-hwe-5.8-headers-5.8.0-41 linux-hwe-5.8-headers-5.8.0-43
  ncal python-dbus python-gi python3-entrypoints
  python3-packaging syslinux syslinux-common syslinux-legacy
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
46 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up php7.4-common (7.4.9-1ubuntu1.1) ...
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
dpkg: error processing package php7.4-common (--configure):
 installed php7.4-common package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 139
Setting up linux-image-5.8.0-41-generic (5.8.0-41.46) ...
Setting up linux-image-5.8.0-43-generic (5.8.0-43.49) ...
Setting up openjdk-11-jre-headless:amd64 (11.0.10+9-0ubuntu1~20.10) ...
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
dpkg: error processing package openjdk-11-jre-headless:amd64 (--configure):
 installed openjdk-11-jre-headless:amd64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 139
Setting up rsyslog (8.2006.0-2ubuntu1) ...
The user `syslog' is already a member of `adm'.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
dpkg: error processing package rsyslog (--configure):
 installed rsyslog package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 139
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php7.4-readline:
 php7.4-readline depends on php7.4-common (= 7.4.9-1ubuntu1.1); however:
  Package php7.4-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php7.4-readline (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of openjdk-11-jre:amd64:
 openjdk-11-jre:amd64 depends on openjdk-11-jre-headless (= 11.0.10+9-0ubuntu1~20.10); however:
  Package openjdk-11-jre-headless:amd64 is not configured yet.

No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              
dpkg: error processing package openjdk-11-jre:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php7.4-cli:
 php7.4-cli depends on php7.4-common (= 7.4.9-1ubuntu1.1); however:
  Package php7.4-common is not configured yet.
 php7.4-cli depends on php7.4-readline; however:
  Package php7.4-readline is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php7.4-cli (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Setting up locales (2.32-0ubuntu3) ...
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
dpkg: error processing package locales (--configure):
 installed locales package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 139
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Setting up grub-pc (2.04-1ubuntu35.4) ...
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
dpkg: error processing package grub-pc (--configure):
 installed grub-pc package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 139
Setting up unattended-upgrades (2.7) ...
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
dpkg: error processing package unattended-upgrades (--configure):
 installed unattended-upgrades package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 139
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php7.4:
 php7.4 depends on php7.4-common; however:
  Package php7.4-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php7.4 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              
Setting up libreoffice-common (1:7.0.3-0ubuntu0.20.10.1) ...
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-common (--configure):
 installed libreoffice-common package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 139
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              
Setting up openjdk-8-jre-headless:amd64 (Core was generated by `awk -v b=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64 /^Alternative:/ && $2~b {p=1} /^Pri'.
8u282-b08-0ubuntu1~20.10) ...
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
dpkg: error processing package openjdk-8-jre-headless:amd64 (--configure):
 installed openjdk-8-jre-headless:amd64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 139
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-gnome:
 libreoffice-gnome depends on libreoffice-common (>= 1:7.0.0~alpha~); however:
  Package libreoffice-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-gnome (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-impress:
 libreoffice-impress depends on libreoffice-common (>= 1:7.0.0~alpha~); however:
  Package libreoffice-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-impress (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                             
Setting up gdm3 (3.38.1-2ubuntu1.1) ...
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
dpkg: error processing package gdm3 (--configure):
 installed gdm3 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 139
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                          
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php7.4-opcache:
 php7.4-opcache depends on php7.4-common (= 7.4.9-1ubuntu1.1); however:
  Package php7.4-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php7.4-opcache (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-help-en-us:
 libreoffice-help-en-us depends on libreoffice-common (>= 1:6.1.0~); however:
  Package libreoffice-common is not configured yet.
 libreoffice-help-en-us depends on libreoffice-l10n-en-us; however:
  Package libreoffice-l10n-en-us is not installed.
  Package libreoffice-common which provides libreoffice-l10n-en-us is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-help-en-us (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of language-pack-gnome-en-base:
 language-pack-gnome-en-base depends on locales (>= 2.3.6); however:
  Package locales is not configured yeNo apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                  No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                              t.

dpkg: error processing package language-pack-gnome-en-base (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-uno:
 python3-uno depends on libreoffice-common (>= 1:7.0.0~alpha~); however:
  Package libreoffice-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-uno (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-core:
 libreoffice-core depends on libreoffice-common (>> 1:7.0.3); however:
  Package libreoffice-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-core (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Setting up fwupd (1.4.5-1) ...
fwupd-offline-update.service is a disabled or a static unit not running, not starting it.
fwupd-refresh.service is a disabled or a static unit not running, not starting it.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
dpkg: error processing package fwupd (--configure):
 installed fwupd package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 139
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Setting up linux-image-5.8.0-36-generic (5.8.0-36.40) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-calc:
 libreoffice-calc depends on libreoffice-common (>= 1:7.0.0~alpha~); however:
  Package libreoffice-common is not configured yet.
 libreoffice-calc depends on libreoffice-core (= 1:7.0.3-0ubuntu0.20.10.1); however:
  Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-calc (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libapache2-mod-php7.4:
 libapache2-mod-php7.4 depends on php7.4-cli; however:
  Package php7.4-cli is not configured yet.
 libapache2-mod-php7.4 depends on php7.4-common (= 7.4.9-1ubuntu1.1); however:
  Package php7.4-common is not configured yet.
 libapache2-mod-php7.4 depends on php7.4-opcache; however:
  Package php7.4-opcache is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libapache2-mod-php7.4 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                          No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                      dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-core:
 gnome-core depends on gdm3 (>= 3.30); however:
  Package gdm3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gnome-core (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-math:
 libreoffice-math depends on libreoffice-common (>= 1:7.0.0~alpha~); however:
  Package libreoffice-common is not configured yet.
 libreoffice-math depends on libreoffice-core (= 1:7.0.3-0ubuntu0.20.10.1); however:
  Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-math (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-desktop:
 ubuntu-desktop depends on gdm3; however:
  Package gdm3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-desktop (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-gtk3:
 libreoffice-gtk3 depends on libreoffice-core (= 1:7.0.3-0ubuntu0.20.10.1); however:
  Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-gtk3 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of language-pack-gnome-en:
 language-pack-gnome-en depends on language-pack-gnome-en-base (>= 1:20.10+20201015); however:
  Package language-pack-gnome-en-base is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package language-pack-gnome-en (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of language-pack-en-base:
 language-pack-en-base depends on locales (>= 2.3.6); however:
  Package locales is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package language-pack-en-base (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php:
 php depends on php7.4; however:
  Package php7.4 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php7.4-json:
 php7.4-json depends on php7.4-common (= 7.4.9-1ubuntu1.1); however:
  Package php7.4-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php7.4-json (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-writer:
 libreoffice-writer depends on libreoffice-common (>= 1:7.0.0~alpha~); however:
  Package libreoffice-common is not configured yet.
 libreoffice-writer depends on libreoffice-core (= 1:7.0.3-0ubuntu0.20.10.1); however:
  Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-writer (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of grub-efi-amd64-signed:
 grub-efi-amd64-signed depends on grub-efi-amd64 | grub-pc; however:
  Package grub-efi-amd64 is not installed.
  Package grub-pc is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64-signed (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-pdfimport:
 libreoffice-pdfimport depends on libreoffice-common (>= 1:5.4~); however:
  Package libreoffice-common is not configured yet.
 libreoffice-pdfimport depends on libreoffice-core (>= 1:5.4~); however:
  Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-pdfimport (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-draw:
 libreoffice-draw depends on libreoffice-common (>= 1:7.0.0~alpha~); however:
  Package libreoffice-common is not configured yet.
 libreoffice-draw depends on libreoffice-core (= 1:7.0.3-0ubuntu0.20.10.1); however:
  Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-draw (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-desktop-minimal:
 ubuntu-desktop-minimal depends on gdm3; however:
  Package gdm3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-desktop-minimal (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome:
 gnome depends on gnome-core (= 1:3.30+3); however:
  Package gnome-core is not configured yet.
 gnome depends on libreoffice-gnome; however:
  Package libreoffice-gnome is not configured yet.
 gnome depends on libreoffice-writer; however:
  Package libreoffice-writer is not configured yet.
 gnome depends on libreoffice-calc; however:
  Package libreoffice-calc is not configured yet.
 gnome depends on libreoffice-impress; however:
  Package libreoffice-impress is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gnome (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of fwupd-signed:
 fwupd-signed depends on fwupd (= 1.4.5-1); however:
  Package fwupd is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package fwupd-signed (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of openjdk-8-jre:amd64:
 openjdk-8-jre:amd64 depends on openjdk-8-jre-headless (= 8u282-b08-0ubuntu1~20.10); however:
  Package openjdk-8-jre-headless:amd64 is not configured yet.

No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                          dpkg: error processing package openjdk-8-jre:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of shim-signed:
 shim-signed depends on grub-efi-amd64-signed | grub-efi-arm64-signed; however:
  Package grub-efi-amd64-signed is not configured yet.
  Package grub-efi-arm64-signed is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package shim-signed (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-help-common:
 libreoffice-help-common depends on libreoffice-common; however:
  Package libreoffice-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-help-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of language-pack-en:
 language-pack-en depends on language-pack-en-base (>= 1:20.10+20201015); however:
  Package language-pack-en-base is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package language-pack-en (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-base-core:
 libreoffice-base-core depends on libreoffice-core (= 1:7.0.3-0ubuntu0.20.10.1) | libreoffice-core-nogui (= 1:7.0.3-0ubuntu0.20.10.1); however:
  Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.
  Package libreoffice-core-nogui is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-base-core (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Processing triggers for linux-image-5.8.0-41-generic (5.8.0-41.46) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal:
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal exited with return code 139
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.8.0-41-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-5.8.0-41-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Processing triggers for linux-image-5.8.0-43-generic (5.8.0-43.49) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal:
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal exited with return code 139
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.8.0-43-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-5.8.0-43-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Processing triggers for linux-image-5.8.0-36-generic (5.8.0-36.40) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal:
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal exited with return code 139
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.8.0-36-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-5.8.0-36-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 php7.4-common
 openjdk-11-jre-headless:amd64
 rsyslog
 php7.4-readline
 openjdk-11-jre:amd64
 php7.4-cli
 locales
 grub-pc
 unattended-upgrades
 php7.4
 libreoffice-common
 openjdk-8-jre-headless:amd64
 libreoffice-gnome
 libreoffice-impress
 gdm3
 php7.4-opcache
 libreoffice-help-en-us
 language-pack-gnome-en-base
 python3-uno
 libreoffice-core
 fwupd
 libreoffice-calc
 libapache2-mod-php7.4
 gnome-core
 libreoffice-math
 ubuntu-desktop
 libreoffice-gtk3
 language-pack-gnome-en
 language-pack-en-base
 php
 php7.4-json
 libreoffice-writer
 grub-efi-amd64-signed
 libreoffice-pdfimport
 libreoffice-draw
 ubuntu-desktop-minimal
 gnome
 fwupd-signed
 openjdk-8-jre:amd64
 shim-signed
 libreoffice-help-common
 language-pack-en
 libreoffice-base-core
 linux-image-5.8.0-41-generic
 linux-image-5.8.0-43-generic
 linux-image-5.8.0-36-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Sample Core Dump: Here is a sample core dump from the segfaults. Core was generated by `awk -v b=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64 /^Alternative:/ && $2~b {p=1} /^Pri'`. It seems to be caused by an issue with Awk.

Will I need to reinstall the system completely afresh from a disc? I can use the system, I just can't upgrade any software or remove it. Thanks for any help! (Also, I will use a pastebin if needed for more output.)

[Here](https://pastebin.com/KxKAmV5M) is the result of running apt upgrade with Valgrind.

Comment: The same issue occurs if I run: 

sudo dpkg --configure -a

Or

sudo apt-get -f install

Comment: From these errors, many say that you have dependency problems and you have a lot of them.  The first part of the error also tells you that you have older versions of software that need to be removed with `sudo apt autoremove`.  Did you run `sudo apt update` before running other commands in `apt`? You need to do this so that your package manager is working with an updated list of available software. I don't usually see issues this bad unless there are already severe problems with your package management system, or long-neglected system maintenance. When's the last time you updated successfully?

Comment: Hi @Nmath, thanks for commenting! I ran sudo apt-update, and it's output was as expected. I run sudo apt autoremove, and it returns the same errors as above.

Incidentally, how do I clear MaxReports so I can access a proper apport report.

I updated to groovy gorilla, but I'm feeling that I'll have to backup some of my stuff and reinstall Ubuntu 20.04 in order to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyone who reads this, take note: PLEASE backup any important documents and just boot and install from disk. It will make life much easier.